# Removing Queue Table Items / Queue UI Module D7

Tags: queue

While attempting to export the mysql database, I found that there was a large number of items in the drupal 7 queue tables "feeds_importer_expire" and "feeds_source_import", both have about 80,000+ records dating back over a year.

I have installed the Queue UI module but have a question before I proceed.

In the "Queue Manager" at "admin/config/system/queue-ui" there is a delete queues button. If I delete the queue e.g. "feeds_importer_expire" will it regenerate the next time it is needed? Or am I deleting the queue all together and causing major issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Drupal supplied queues only exist when they have `$items` within them. It will be regenerated when it's next inserted into.

Depending on whether or not a worker process is working on a `claimed item` the queue item(s) when you delete the queue -- you may raise like a warning when the process tries to notify the queue of completion of an item. It shouldn't break the queue itself; the worker processes may need to be reset of course.

Comment: Thanks, I performed the action and deleted the queue and received the following message "All items in each queue will be deleted, regardless of if leases exist. This operation cannot be undone." This language clarifies that it is deleting the "items" not the "table"